# Uncheck vue radio button from another button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table with a list of records and each record with two associated radio buttons, one to confirm payment and another to reject, when I pick up on any of the radio buttons I get a modal screen with two buttons, one to definitively confirm a payment and the other to cancel if the wrong radio button is marked, what I need is that when I click on the cancel button, the radio button that I had initially marked is unchecked

[See Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRYwZ.png)

[See Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weKJV.png)

This is my code in Vue:

```
<v-col class="text-center">                           
                  <span class="radio-registered pt-1 px-1">
                    <input type="radio" 
                    @change="dlgComments = !dlgComments; setUpdateData(1, 2, flt.user_payment_id, flt.payment_amount, flt.pay_date, flt.email, flt.user_name, flt.due_concept, flt.payment_reference, flt.student_due_detail_id); sendInfo(flt), sendInputId(`filter${f}`)" 
                    :name="`filter${f}`" 
                    :checked="false">
                  </span>           
                </v-col>

                <v-col class="text-center">         
                  <span class="radio-rejected pt-1 px-1">
                    <input type="radio" 
                    @change="dlgComments = !dlgComments; setUpdateData(2, 3, flt.user_payment_id, flt.payment_amount, flt.pay_date, flt.email, flt.user_name, flt.due_concept, flt.payment_reference, flt.student_due_detail_id); sendInfo(flt)" 
                    :name="`filter${f}`" 
                    :checked="false">
                  </span>     
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
```

I'm relatively new to Vue and I don't know which property I should add. Thanks sorry for my English !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You would need to add a key in data to manage the checked state of the radio, for example 'isChecked':

   ```
   data () {
    return {
      isChecked: true,
    }
   }
   ```
2. Bind checked state of the input to the data property:

```html
<input type="radio":checked="isChecked">
```

3. Set the click event of another button to toggle/clear the check (depends on what you want to do) to a function that change the data property (for example I want to toggle the radio button):

```html
<button @click="toggleCheckedState">Toggle</button>
```

And the function to toggle the state (defined in methods):

```
methods:{
  toggleCheckedState(){
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked; //example
    //your logic
  },
}
```